# Increase size of Google Document Site Wide

Tags: embed, google

How do I increase the size of an embedded Google document in Wordpress site wide. Without the need to add css `width="100%" height="800px"` to every iframe.

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QFvpre76QuZ9xWXGu3FV1hqSlEWcxqln57wbKjku56s/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>
```

Example:

http://www.idolovewords.com/portfolio-item/transcritical-co2-system/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-auto-100-height) contains a solution. It seems the parent element needs a width declaration of 100%, which allows the iframe element to use that 100% width.